# Adding second disk to k8s nodes

Tags: kubernetes, nodes, disk

I created a k8s cluster, so now I have to add a second disk to my node

This is my node group configuration

```
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "node_group" {
  cluster_name = aws_eks_cluster.pm_eks.name
  node_group_name = "${var.appConfig_subdomain}-NodeGroup"
  node_role_arn = aws_iam_role.node-group-iam-role.arn
  subnet_ids = [
    aws_subnet.node-a_subnet.id,
    aws_subnet.node-b_subnet.id,
    aws_subnet.node-c_subnet.id
  ]
  instance_types = [
    "${var.aws_node_size}"
  ]
  disk_size = "${var.aws_node_diskSize}"
  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 3
    max_size     = 5
    min_size     = 3
  }
  remote_access {
    ec2_ssh_key = aws_key_pair.nodegroup-kp.key_name
    source_security_group_ids = [
      aws_security_group.allow_dmz.id
    ]
  } 
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo '${tls_private_key.nodegroup-kp.private_key_pem}' > ./${var.appConfig_subdomain}-${var.appConfig_env}-nodegroup.pem"
  }
  # Ensure that IAM Role permissions are created before and deleted after EKS Node Group handling.
  # Otherwise, EKS will not be able to properly delete EC2 Instances and Elastic Network Interfaces.
  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly,
  ]
}
```

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to add a 2nd disk to your nodes, thats not an ideal way in Kubernetes, you should checkout `PersistentVolumeClaims` & `PersistentVolumes` in Kubernetes, that will automatically add a disk for your respective pod and attach it to the respective node where the pod is running. But its not recommended to add a disk to the worker node.

Comment: I'm one of those who likes to keep root volume separate from where container images are stored because it grows pretty fast and I don't know how effective would kubelet garbage collection will be. Wouldn't the be a good case for this?